# js field validation - loop through object with three data considerations per field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Titling this question is a killer. Improvements welcome.

For field validation, I need three data elements per field: varname, element ID, and required(t/f).

I cannot figure out the logic, though. I am good with an associative-type object, but adding-in the required yes/no bit is more than I can figure out.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdLwntpo/1/)

```
HTML:

<input id="fld_1" class="input" type="text" value="bob" /><br>
<input id="fld_2" class="input" type="text" value="" /><br>
<input id="fld_3" class="input" type="text" value="pat" /><br>
<input id="mybutt" class="btn" type="button" value="Test" />

js/jQ:

objFields = {'f1':'fld_1', 'f2':'fld_2', 'f3':'fld_3'};
arrErrors = [];

$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    for (var key in objFields){
        var tmp = objFields[key];
        eval('var ' + key+ ' = $("#' +tmp+ '").val()');
        alert( key +' => '+ eval(key) );
        //IF contents required and field is empty, error and return false
    }
});
```

Here's the key part, though: I need to add a third datum to the assoc array (which means it will no longer be an assoc array) to indicate which fields are *required*.  For example, suppose the 2nd field is the only one that is required to be completed.  How do I add that third parameter to the object, and then use it in the validation loop?

Comment: Avoid using eval and user entered information, it is dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Travis. [I'm aware of the traps](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/) but believe this the most efficient code solution. If you have another, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/gmwf9u69/)***

Since you went through the effort of composing the object with the identifiers, you can just use `.each` to iterate over that and then take the string value of key and use them in a jQuery selector. It will be much safer than using eval. Then all you need to do is trim the value from those elements and make sure they aren't empty.

*edit* "Add a property to the object in order to filter required elements"

In this case, I believe you are going to make the 'fld_' portion into an object itself, and with it could be an id and a requirement boolean. And then check in the iteration for the boolean value and skip when the requirement is false.

```js
var boolish = {
 'True' : true, 'False' : false,
 'true' : true, 'false' : false,
};
var objFields = {
 'f1': { 'id' : 'fld_1', 'required' : 'True' } ,
 'f2': { 'id' : 'fld_2', 'required' : 'False' } ,
 'f3': { 'id' : 'fld_3', 'required' : 'true' }
};//often booleans from server side come back in strings
var arrErrors = [];

$('#mybutt').click(function(){
  arrErrors = [];
 //IF contents required and field is empty, error and return false
 $.each(objFields,function(_,val){
  if(!boolish[val.required])return true;//skip required = false (return true is jQuery for continue)
  if($("#"+val.id).val().trim() == "")arrErrors.push(_);
 });
 console.log(arrErrors);
});
```

```css
.input{width:150px;margin:10px;background:aliceblue;}
.btn{margin:30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fld_1" class="input" type="text" value="bob" /><br>
<input id="fld_2" class="input" type="text" value="" /><br>
<input id="fld_3" class="input" type="text" value="pat" /><br>
<input id="mybutt" class="btn" type="button" value="Test" />
```

Comment: Hi Travis, my question wasn't clear - very sorry. I need to add a third data to the assoc array to indicate which fields are required.  For example, suppose the 2nd field is the only one that is required.  How do I add that third parameter to the object, and then use it in the loop?  If you can answer, I suggest leaving this answer as is and creating another so I can upvote both.

Comment: @crashwap - Would you rather have the information for the requirement on the object or the element?

Comment: In the object is what I need.  Modifying the html is a good idea, but I need it in the object.

Comment: @crashwap - (1) The underscore is to indicate that field is not being used (it is an int representation of the index you can use with `.each`). (2) The reason your version looks like it isn't working (it is though), is because the second field which is empty has `'required' : 'False'` as its setting. If you change that to `'required' : 'True'` then you will see an alert.